# ¿Cuál es el lugar correcto de colocar el verbo: ¿Quién (eres) tú (eres)?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, preguntas, orden-de-palabras

*¿Quién tú eres?* o *¿Quién eres tú?*

¿Cuál debe ser la posición del verbo en esa oración?

Answer (score 4):

Ambas posiciones son perfectamente válidas.

No obstante, lo más común es simplemente *¿Quién eres?*, ya que el verbo nos relata quién es el sujeto.  En el caso de querer darle énfasis, la *mayoría* de los hablantes colocarán el verbo antes del sujeto, es decir, *¿Quién eres tú?*.  Pero en el Caribe, es común escuchar el verbo pospuesto al sujeto: *¿Quién tú eres?*

Yo creo que para muchos hablantes, decir algo como *¿Quién tú eres?* te identificaría como un hablante caribeño porque es tan poco extendido en el resto del mundo hispanohablante.